# Detrending time series data prior to PCA

Tags: time-series, pca

In a recent conversation with a colleague who has much more experience in statistics, she commented that I should detrend my time series data (using a linear model) prior to undertaking PCA. I'm struggling to understand the rationale, as the reason I am performing PCA is to characterise the variability and detrending is removing arguably the most interesting variability. One argument I've read was that assumptions are violated when the data is non-stationary. As PCA doesn't consider the (chronological) order of the data it's not clear to me why this would be an issue.

My questions are: 1) is it necessary to detrend my data prior to performing PCA? I suspect, yes, so my second question is 2) why? Finally, 3) what biases or problems will I generate by not detrending the data?

---

Edit to answer the question from amoeba below. My data set describes environment variables relating to a region of ocean (e.g., temperature, salinity, NAO index, etc.). My goal is to identify modes of variability and variables associated with these modes.

Comment: It's clearly not *necessary*. Whether it's *useful*, will I guess heavily depend on what are applying PCA to and on what you are intending to use the PCA for. So I suggest you add this information.

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for you comment. I've added some more text to the question.

Comment: I've never thought about PCA in the context of time series, but in ordinary PCA one removes the mean from the observations.  Perhaps that is what your colleague was driving at.

Comment: @aginensky I don't think that was her point, as we'd already discussed centering and scaling the data. She specifically mentioned fitting a linear model to remove the long term trend before performing the PCA.

Comment: "My goal is to identify modes of variability and variables associated with these modes" -- well, then whether to detrend or not to detrend depends on whether you want to consider linear trends an interesting/relevant "mode of variability".

Comment: the point is: if you think that *there* is a linear trend in your data, well it's a good idea to remove it in order to have the PCA "focus" on the rest of the variability. If you keep the data untrended, probably the first mode you get will be one associated to the linear trend. Furthermore, I am quite sure that it makes sense also from a statistical point-of-view, when you have non-stationary data for example you do not use correlation and co-variance...